# Why does the score of TPOT recommend classifier is lower than LinearSVC?

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

So I have found out that LinearSVC is in TPOT classifier and I have been using it for my model and get a pretty decent score (0.95 in sklearn score).

```
def process(stock):
  df = format_data(stock)
  df[['HSI Volume', 'HSI', stock]] = df[['HSI Volume', 'HSI', stock]].pct_change()

# shift future value to current date
  df[stock+'_future'] = df[stock].shift(-1)
  df.replace([-np.inf, np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)
  df.dropna(inplace=True)
  df['class'] = list(map(create_labels, df[stock], df[stock+'_future']))
  X = np.array(df.drop(['class', stock+'_future'], 1)) # 1 = column
  # X = preprocessing.scale(X)
  y = np.array(df['class'])

  X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

  tpot = TPOTClassifier(generations = 10, verbosity=2)
  fitting = tpot.fit(X_train, y_train)
  prediction = tpot.score(X_test, y_test)
  tpot.export('pipeline.py')
  return fitting, prediction
```

After ten generations: TPOT recommended GaussianNB and it scores about 0.77 in sklearn score.

```
Generation 1 - Current best internal CV score: 0.5322255571                     
Generation 2 - Current best internal CV score: 0.55453535828                    
Generation 3 - Current best internal CV score: 0.55453535828                    
Generation 4 - Current best internal CV score: 0.55453535828                    
Generation 5 - Current best internal CV score: 0.587469903893                   
Generation 6 - Current best internal CV score: 0.587469903893                   
Generation 7 - Current best internal CV score: 0.597194474469                   
Generation 8 - Current best internal CV score: 0.597194474469                   
Generation 9 - Current best internal CV score: 0.597194474469                   
Generation 10 - Current best internal CV score: 0.597194474469                  

Best pipeline: GaussianNB(RBFSampler(input_matrix, 0.22))
(None, 0.54637855142056824)
```

I am just curious that why LinearSVC scores higher but TPOT did not recommend. Is it because of the scoring mechanism is different and hence lead to a different optimal classifier?

Thank you so much!

Comment: The reason is that the generation is not long enough and the classifier is underfitting the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal guess is that tpot is stuck on a local maximum, maybe try to change test size, do more generations or scaling the data could help. Also, could you redo the TPOT and see if you get the same results? (My guess is no, since genetic optimization is non-deterministic due to mutation)

Comment: You are right, I solve the problem by adding more generations to TPOT and achieves a higher accuracy.